# Update the Mat Dialog data on deletion Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I have implemented a mat dialog table. It has 3 columns `name, email and delete icon` When I click delete it confirms if we want to delete and on delete, it removes the item from database. But I am not able to see the changes immediately, I have to close the dialog box and open it again to see changes. How can I update the changes immediately.
TS CODE:

```
//parent component has a master table. On click of name we open mat table with nested user list to delete from
delete(name){ 
    //backend logic
           if(response.status === 400){
               //show error message
          } else {
            //open dialog table
            this.openDialog(userData);
          }} })}
   
   openDialog(us, c){
   // some logic
     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogExample, {
         width: '700px',
         height: '500px',
         data: {arrayDialog: this.allUsers, c}
       });
     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
       console.log('the dialog was closed');
       this.allUsers = [];
     });}}

//child component to open mat dialog table
  @Component({
    selector: 'dialog--example',
    templateUrl: 'dialog.html',
  })
  export class DialogExample {
    readonly userColumns: string[] = ['name', 'email', 'delete'];
   
    delete(email, uName){ 
     //some logic
    confirmationDialog(e,c) {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialog,{
        data:{
          message: 'Please confirm the deletion',
          buttonText: {
            ok: 'Delete',
            cancel: 'Cancel'
          }} });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
        if (confirmed) {
          //After closing the confirmation dialog, here I want to update the mat dialog table to show updated data excluding the deleted user details.
        } });}}

  @Component({
    selector: 'deleteconfirm',
    templateUrl: 'deleteconfirm.html',
  })
  export class ConfirmationDialog {
   
returns true if confirmed 
returns false if cancelled
```

How can I update it? Should I call `delete(name)` function. I tried but as it is on parent component it gives error that cannot find it. How should I proceed thanks.

Answer (score 0):

return deleted record id to parent on dialog close and filter data with that deleted record id

parent.component.ts

```
  openDialog(us, c){
      // some logic
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogExample, {
          width: '700px',
          height: '500px',
          data: {arrayDialog: this.allUsers, c}
        });
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log('the dialog was closed');
          this.allUsers =this.allUsers.filter(item=>item.id!==result.id);
      });
  }}
```

dialogExample.component.ts

```
export class DialogExample {

constructor(private dialogExampleRef: MatDialogRef<DialogExample>) { }
readonly userColumns: string[] = ['name', 'email', 'delete'];

delete(email, uName){ 
 //some logic
confirmationDialog(e,c) {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialog,{
    data:{
      message: 'Please confirm the deletion',
      buttonText: {
        ok: 'Delete',
        cancel: 'Cancel'
      }} });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
      if (confirmed) {
        //After closing the confirmation dialog, here I want to update the mat dialog table to show updated data excluding the deleted user details.
          this.dialogExampleRef.close({ e })
    } });}}
```

Comment: what if there is no ```id```? I am actually passing ```email``` and ```c``` value to check which user is to be deleted. How can I accomplish it then? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: few things, how would I be sending data to parent component? I mean I get a true value for ```confirmed``` and then will I have to implement something?

Comment: once confirmed you can return value(email or any unique values) back to parent  ` this.dialogRef.close({ email})`,  if not confirmed you can simply close the  DialogExample 
component  by ` this.dialogRef.close({ email:null})` , then in parent you can filter the users list

Comment: can you please tell what is  ```item```  in the code?

Comment: I tried implementing the updated solution but it is just closing the entire dialog box and also not actually removing the data. I only want to close the confirmation dialog and update the mat-dialog-table

Comment: mat-dialog-table is in parent component or where?

Comment: Yes it is on the parent component only.